# Java Triangle class, getArea method constantly returning 0.0?

Tags: java, methods, geometry, area

This is a homework assignment. We have to create a Triangle class with a bunch of methods, and all of them work EXCEPT my getArea method. I'm using the formula from the textbook for calculating are, but it constantly returns 0.0 or -0.0. Please help!

Here's my area formula/method. Please note that the `area` variable was declared as a `private double` earlier in the code. I've tried everything I could think of:

```
    public double getArea(){
    double f = 0.0;
    double num = 0.0;

    f = (1/2) * (this.side1 + this.side2 + this.side3);
    num = (f) * ((f - this.side1) * (f - this.side2) * (f - this.side3));        
    area = Math.sqrt(num);

    return area;
}
```

Comment: `(1/2)` is 0. Don't do int division! Instead do:   `f = (1.0 / 2.0) * ....` or `f = 0.5 * ...`

Comment: Note, the duplicate link is not exact, but I wanted to close this question quickly, since we really don't need another one of these hanging around.

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for the duplicate, I didn't even think to look at integer division topics. I did go through all the suggested questions based on my title, but they were a little more advanced than what I was doing, so I assumed it was okay to ask in this manner.